# How to make phpunit reload in a console application using php

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm creating a console application to help me develop my website in php.
The console application runs in a while loop, prints a menu with options and I'll input a number to tell the application what I want it to do. In One of my option I am running phpunit test, when I run the test it works but when I update my test and press my option again, phpunit displays "No tests executed!". When I restart the console app it will work but i still have the same problem when I try to run the unit test second time.

Here is a code example

I have tired instantiating a new phpunit command and then use the run method.

I have tried breaking out of the loop and call begin again.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

public function printMenu()
{
     echo "*******menu*****";
     echo "\r\n";
     echo "option 1: do something";
     echo "\r\n";
     echo "option 2: Do unit test:";
     echo "\r\n";
     echo "option 3: Exit";
     echo "\r\n";
}

public function begin(){

    while(true){
       $this->printMenu();
       $input = trim(fgets(STDIN));

       if($input == 1){
         $this->doSomething();
       }else if($input ==2){
         PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main(false);
       }else if($input == 3){
        break;
       }
    }
}

//Sample test class (just an example)

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase; 
class SampleTest extends TestCase 
{
   public function testTrueAssertsToTrue(): void { 
      $this->assertTrue(true); 
      $this->assertTrue(true); 
      $this->assertTrue(false); 
      $this->assertTrue(true); 
      $this->assertTrue(true); 
    }
}

//update will be

 use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase; 

class SampleTest extends TestCase 
{ 
     public function testTrueAssertsToTrue(): void 
     { 
         $this->assertTrue(true); 
         $this->assertTrue(true); 
         $this->assertTrue(true); 
         $this->assertTrue(true); 
         $this->assertTrue(true); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by changing

```
PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main(false);
```

to

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```